# UIScrollview not scrolling interface builder

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, scrollview

I am adding `UIScrollView` from Interface builder to my `xib` file. The `scrollview` is a child of `ViewController's` view and it also has some other siblings which are on `ViewController's` view.

Now i am setting the `contentSize` of the `scrollview` in `viewDidLoad` method and also tried to set this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method but the `scrollview` doesn't scroll. I am sure that the content area of my `scrollview` is bigger than the frame of the `scollview`.

Every thing works fine when i add `scrollview` in my code using the following line

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 58.0, 282.0, 200.0)]
```

but it didn't scroll at all when use the `IBOutlet` in my code here is my code for `viewDidLoad` with `scollView` from Interface builder.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ALog();

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    float margin = 0.0;
    UIImage *previewImg = nil;
    for (i = 0; i < [[_settingsDict objectForKey:@"fullscreenWidgetIDsArray"] count]; i++) {
        previewImg = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%@", _dict[@"images"][i]]];


        if (previewImg == nil) {
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_2.png"];
        }

        UIImage *backgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_border.png"];
        UIImage *backgroundHighlightedImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_selected.png"];
        BOOL selected = [_dict[@"images"][i] unsignedIntegerValue] == [_dict[@"ID"] unsignedIntegerValue];

        UIImageView *gridElementView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImg];
        [gridElementView setHighlightedImage:backgroundHighlightedImg];
        [gridElementView setHighlighted:selected];
        gridElementView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(6, 5, previewImg.size.width, previewImg.size.height);
        [button setImage:previewImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

        margin = (_scrollView.frame.size.width - kElements_per_row * (gridElementView.frame.size.width + 2*kPreview_border_size))/3;

        gridElementView.frame = CGRectMake(margin + i%2*(margin + gridElementView.frame.size.width + 2*kPreview_border_size), margin + i/2*(margin + gridElementView.frame.size.height + 2*kPreview_border_size), gridElementView.frame.size.width + 2*kPreview_border_size, gridElementView.frame.size.height + 2*kPreview_border_size);


        button.tag = gridElementView.tag = [_settingsDict[@"fullscreenWidgetIDsArray"][i] unsignedIntegerValue];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(previewBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_thumbnailsViewsArray addObject:gridElementView];

        [gridElementView addSubview:button];
        [_scrollView addSubview:gridElementView];

    }

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, margin + (i/2)*(margin + previewImg.size.height + 2*kPreview_border_size));

    NSLog(@"contentsize : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(_scrollView.contentSize));


}
```

In this code i am adding `UIButtons` inside `scrollview` in two columns. There are total 6 `UIButtons` that needs to be added in `scrollview`. These button were added but `scrollview` will not scroll at all. Making the `scrollEnabled` property to yes also didn't work.

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Try to print the height of the scroll view vs it's content size height. (Print it to the console). Just to make sure.

Comment: yes check size of both scrollview and content size.
or set test contenent size by commenting your setcontent line and put.
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000 ,2000);

Comment: ScrollView Frame : {{20, 58}, {282, 275}}    Scrollview Contentsize : {282, 362.66666}